# AWS Forecast Inference optimization

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-forecast

Current behavior :

- target series of 1320 data points, which has an hourly frequency, until a specific date (let's say: `2020-01-30 23:00:00`)
- related time series from the same date and includes information for the next hour, (e.g. `2020-01-31 00:00:00`)
- a Prophet predictor with a horizon of prediction of 1 hour

The approach is to obtain the data for the last recent hour, and include it to the target series (and related time series), in order to forecast the following period.
Here is the steps :

- Save the recent updated target time series to S3
- Import the data into Forecast using `forecast.create_dataset_import_job`
- Delete previous Forecast using `forecast.delete_forecast`
- Create a new Forecast (without retraining the predictor) using `forecast.create_forecast`

But the main issue is that the forecast creation takes up to 30 minutes, so is there a way to make the inference faster? or change the approach to optimize the time for doing so?

Comment: Hello, I'm editing your question. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to ask with a good behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)

Comment: 1. This process you describe is the "cold start" process and as documented [here][1] is only supposed to work with DeepAR+ (you seem to be using Prophet).
2. I do not think you can get it faster.


  [1]: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-forecast-samples/blob/master/notebooks/advanced/Forecast%20with%20Cold%20Start%20Items/Forecast%20with%20Cold%20Start%20Items.ipynb

Comment: I don't think "cold start" that is what the OP is looking for. I understand he wants to speed-up the process of uploading new data for inference, for example, as new data points come with time, you ant to keep predicting one hour in the future